# MOSFET-enhancemement-depletion-n type-p type

Tags: mosfet, depletion-mode

Can someone please explain me the difference of n-channel enhancement, n-channel depletion and p-channel enhancement, p-channel depletion because I am confused.
Correct me if I am wrong but the n-channel/p-channel indicates the charge of the channel formed between the source and drain?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Now, that's just being lazy... even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) has more info on this than could be possibly squeezed into typical answer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n-channel: you must have \$V_{gs} > V_{gs}(th)\$ to turn the FET "on".

n-channel enhancement mode: \$V_{gs}(th) > 0\ V\$.

n-channel depletion mode: \$V_{gs}(th) < 0\ V\$.

p-channel: you must have \$V_{gs} < V_{gs}(th)\$ to turn the FET "on".

p-channel enhancement mode: \$V_{gs}(th) < 0\ V\$.

p-channel depletion mode: \$V_{gs}(th) > 0\ V\$.

In present times, depletion mode devices are rarely seen, so you probably want to focus your attention on how to use enhancement-mode devices.

Comment: Disagree with the last sentence. Depletion mode devices are easily available eg. Ixys/Littelfuse, Infineon, Microchip, Advanced Linear. Really handy in some situations such as input limiters, loop-powered transmitters and N.C. circuits without a power source. Also a number of RF devices. But I don't know of any at all that are P-channel.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I didn't say they're not available, I said they're rarely seen. I'll remove the "very" if that makes you happier.

Comment: I think that one of the main differentiation between the 2 mode is enhancement MOSFET are normally OFF while depletion MOSFET are normally ON.